# Qt Creator C++ Using WebCamera

Tags: c++, qt

I've been programming in QT with C++ for about year.
I've started my own GUI project and everything works fine to this moment.
Now I want to add the option to take pictures with my web camera but I don't know what I should do.

I've read everything about OpenCV library and I've tried to install it but I still don't get the includes in QT. Is there some easier way to access my camera?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Qt 5 you can take a look at [QCamera](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcamera.html#details) and see if it fit your needs, also you can take a look at [camera overview](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/cameraoverview.html) (and as far as i know there is an example, added [camera example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediawidgets-camera.html) link, thanks *Shf*)

Comment: Thank you a lot Zlatomir.Now i will read everything about QCamera and i will try to make this option in my project.Week ago i 've tried with QCamera but i 've got lot of errors.However, i will try again.Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: tried it myself, it works, but for some reason widget with camera can only resize to increase it's size, whet i try to shrink it, it refuses, is there any cure? It's even in qt's examples

Comment: user2521257, what errors are you getting - are you linking with the _multimedia_ module?
   @Shf, no idea about your problem and i can't check right now, but you can add a question regarding your issue - since that way many people can see it and maybe know how to fix that.

Comment: @user2521257 make sure, that you added `QT += multimedia multimediawidgets` to your .pro file.

Comment: @Zlatomir right now, i cannot reproduce it on Qt 5.0.2 and Ubuntu 12.04, but at home on Windows 8 and Qt 5.0.2 it does not shrinks, when i want to resize. Using default QCamera example http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediawidgets-camera.html

By the way, include that in answer, it is probably usefull

Comment: Finally, after writing some bunch of code using QCamera class i' ve made my webcam red light turn on and off. :D I need a few more hours to get the principles and display something in the graphics view.Thanks to all

Comment: @user2521257 if this solved your problem, accept it as an answer, so others, looking for similar problem could see solution, that is correct

Comment: After this day, my problem with the camera was totally solved.There are no more problems.Now i will continue my GUI project thanks to all of you guys.After 1-2 months i will start searching for how to write printer driver ;), but however.Thanks too all again. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use OpenCV with QT Creator, just add include path and libraries.

here is my pro file template for OpenCV.

```
#begin{opencv}
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\opencv\opencv\build\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv"

LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_calib3d231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_contrib231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_core231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_features2d231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_flann231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_gpu231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_haartraining_engine.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_highgui231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_imgproc231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_legacy231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_ml231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_objdetect231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_ts231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_video231.lib
#end{opencv}
```

Comment: I tried it but i still don't get the libraries in the intellisense #include. However thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure paths are correct? I'm using this setting/#include <opencv/cv.hpp> and code completion works as expected.

Comment: Bmeric thank you so much dude! Now i realise that i have been sleeping all the time.I was setting the wrong directories and i have deleted OpenCV from my computer yesterday, cause i was nervous -.- .Now i've changed the directories and installed OpenCv again and i've got the intellisense #include. Now i should only watch some tutorials to learn the library.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bmeric, hi again. I get the includes now but when i write some code using open cv libraries i am getting cv::mat::dealloate() and cv::fastFree(void *) errors.I am trying to solve this for about 11 hours -.-. Can u tell me what should i do please.Thanks

Comment: Are they linking errors? If it is, make sure to use correct libs for your compiler(if you're using visual studio 2008, don't use mingw libs). Take a look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004419/opencv-2-3-doesnt-compile-undefined-reference-error

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Qt Media Encoding Library** to capture images from your webcam..and even encode video from your webcam :)

It is here:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29117/

Comment: Yeah.QT Mel is good variant too.But i can't find any functions and how to use it.Can u provide me some link please? Thanks in advance. ;)